# Preview search function returns blank results

Tags: preview, search

I'm having trouble finding pages when I query for a string in Preview, where actual results are mixed in with meaningless, blank results. For example, when I search for *B-tree* in my algorithms book, I get this:

[image: Search results for "B-tree"]

where page 494 and 495 shouldn't match at all.

Comment: How does it do with another search string

Comment: similar results, for example when I search for "its"

Comment: give me the link so I can download and test

Comment: Found it, downloaded and my preview search does exactly as yours.

Comment: Thanks, guess I'll just stick with Google Chrome's PDF Reader in situations like these.

Comment: You are welcome, sorry could not do better :( If you use Adobe Readers FIND command, it will find each b-tree and highlight it, then you click next ect.. It is not quite what you are looking for for but just an alternative.